# Где хранится словарь с id уведомлений для каждого приложения в Android?

Tags: android, android-notification

Есть ли какие-то способы узнать список id всплывающих уведомлений для каждого приложения? Догадываюсь, что можно вытащить, декомпилировать apk и посмотреть там, но надеюсь, что это можно сделать более простым способом. Возможно где-то в системе хранится такой словарь?

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(THISISID, notification);
```

Еще хотелось бы уточнить, id каждого уведомления должен быть уникален в рамках одного приложения или в рамках всей системы?

Comment: В системе конечно они хранятся, но получить доступ вы можете только к собственным: ['NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()'](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#getActiveNotifications()), соответственно id чужих уведомлений вам ничем не помогут.

Answer (score 0):

ID не обязан быть константой, так что какого-то общего хранилища заранее известных значений быть не может, т.к. может быть использовано текущее время для ID, например.

Уникальность для ID не требуется. И ID уведомлений разных приложений могут одинаковыми, т.к. они никак друг на друга не влияют. Если ID 2 уведомлений одного приложения одинаковы, то второе уведомление заменит первое. Если разные - то отобразятся оба.